# Does madhiy has smell or it does not have at all

Tags: taharah

Does madhiy have smell or it does not have at all how can I distinguish regarding smell.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not seek an Islamic answer; it's just a matter of biology.

Answer (score 2):

Scholars have not described anything about the attribute of the odor of madhy. The main specification of this liquid is its color which is described as white (rather colorless).